# converting mysql query to oracle query

Tags: php, mysql, oracle11g

i changed my data base to oracle and i want to know which code i should change. 
when i tried by my self it didnt work. it gives me

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in  D:\xampp\htdocs\advance_search.php on line 40
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_query() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\advance_search.php on line 44

errors..

```
     <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(!empty($_POST["search"]))  
      {  
           $query = str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST["search"]);  
           header("location:advance_search.php?search=" . $query);  
      }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Search multiple words at a time in Mysql php</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Search multiple words at a time in Mysql php</h3><br />  
                <form method="post">  
                     <label>Enter Search Text</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["search"])) echo $_GET["search"]; ?>" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Search" />  
                </form>  
                <br /><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                     <?php  
                     if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
                     {  
                          $condition = '';  
                          $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);  
                          foreach($query as $text)  
                          {  
                               $condition .= "video_title LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";  
                          }  
                          $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
                          $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_video WHERE " . $condition;  
                          $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);  
                          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                          {  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                               {  
                                    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["video_title"].'</td></tr>';  
                               }  
                          }  
                          else  
                          {  
                               echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  
                          }  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
          </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in D:\xampp\htdocs\advance_search.php on line 40

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in D:\xampp\htdocs\advance_search.php on line 44

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\advance_search.php on line 45
Data not Found

what theses errors mean?

Comment: it worked until connecting oracle data base by using    <?php
 $connect = oci_connect("java01", "java01", "//localhost/xe", "utf8");
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
      if(!empty($_POST["search"]))
      {
           $query = str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST["search"]);
           header("location:advance_search.php?search=" . $query);
      }
 }
 ?>

Comment: Where is `oci_query` call?

Comment: i advice you to use [PDO Oracle driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php) then your code is more future proof and your code base can work for multiple database.. If the SQL code will that is a other question.. Here is the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) manual page

Comment: i dont see one.. but it worked just fine with mysql db...

Comment: `Call to undefined function oci_query() ` wouldn't occur without that code. You're going to have to dive into your code more.

Comment: didnt know its hard to convert mysql db query to oracle db qeury...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I used this method to connect instead

```
<?php   
$db = "(DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = 
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST = [host])
        (PORT = [port])) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = [service_name])))";
    $conn = oci_connect([schema_name], [schema_password], $db);
    if (!$conn) {
    $m = oci_error();
    echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else 
    echo 'connected';?>
```

Comment: Not complicated, straight to the point, able to see what you missing and you'll never go wrong